# Help with Arduino loops please!

Tags: arduino, programming, humidity

So I have an Arduino Uno and I've made a device to humidify my the enclosure for my Tortoise.
The device consists of a temperature and humidity sensor, an LCD screen to display temperature and humidity and a water pump, which comes on if the humidity is below a certain point.

I set the program to loop every ten minutes, so as to not flood the enclosure with too much water but of course that means the LCD screen with only update every ten minutes too.
I want the LCD screen to update every few seconds but the pump to only turn on 10 minutes after it's already been on if the humidity is still too low.

How can I do this?

Here is my code...

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7
int pump = 13;

void setup(){
  pinMode(pump, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int hum = DHT.humidity;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(tmp);
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humidity: ");
  lcd.print(hum);
  lcd.print("%");

  if(hum <= 70) {
    digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
  }

  delay(600000);
}
```

Thanks for your help! =]

Comment: Try the Arduino sites

Comment: thats more a programming question than an electrical.

Comment: Have a shorter delay and a counter.  When the counter gets to a suitable value you run the code that runs the pump then reset the counter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general programming question.

Comment: Lookup **"Blink without delay"**. It's an example code that should have came included with the Arduino IDE. The gist is that you should stop using **delay()** and instead have the micro check each loop if it's time to do something yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a long `delay` use a timestamp of the last time you ran the pump and compare it with millis():

```
// add to globals under pump

unsigned long lastRun = 0;


if(millis() - lastRun > 60*1000){
  if(hum <= 70) {
    digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
    lastRun = millis();
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
  }
}
```

This can be used in a lot of ways to avoid using `delay()` at all.